# Casting TObject to TMenuItem and retrieving caption adds & to string

Tags: delphi

So I have some really simple code below. I am using this function in multiple onclick events to pass in the TMenuItems's caption.

```
procedure TForm1.BtnClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
 TestFrm.MyVar:= TMenuItem(Sender).Caption;
 InteractiveSchedulerFrm.ShowModal;
end;
```

However, the result of this is that the TestFrm.MyVar field ends up having an ampersand included in it that wasn't originally there, and its always in a seemingly random spot.

I have temporarily patched the issue by replacing all ampersands in the string, but I am mostly curious as to whats causing the ampersand to be placed in the string.

Example:

TMenuItem(Sender).Caption = 'TEST';

TestFrm.MyVar = 'TE&ST' or '&TEST' etc

Comment: See AutoHotKeys in documentation.

Comment: Also, http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/Vcl.Menus.StripHotkey

Comment: `TMainMenu.AutoHotKeys` is adding them as accelerator keys. As @SertacAkyuz suggests, see the documentation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The ampersand ist added automatically because you probably have set the AutoHotKeys property of the menu to true (which I think is even the default).

You have got two options:

1. Set AutoHotkeys to false - or -
2. Call StripHotkey (from unit Menus) to remove it before processing the caption

I would probably go for 2, because you never know if somebody (a future you) might not set AutoHotkeys back to true.

Answer (score 0):

The ampersands in TMenuItem captions are used to indicate keyboard shortcuts to the Menu items. The ampersand appears before the shortcut character and underlines the character in some cases to ensure the user knows about the shortcut. This type of character is called an [accelerator character](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Menus_TMenuItem_Caption.html).

For example, a TMenuItem with a caption of `&TEST` could be triggered with an ALT+T keypress, while a TMenuItem with a caption of `TE&ST` could be triggered with an ALT+S keypress.

If you want an ampersand to appear in your menu item caption, you will need to escape it with another ampersand (e.g. `Bacon && Eggs`). [Here is a link to the first source I found about this feature.](http://www.delphigroups.info/2/4c/72486.html)